# Linear Algebra - Question about transformation and characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I have some trouble with this question, I tried to solve it but I'm not sure that my solution is correct.
I'll be glad if somebody could take a look.

Data :

T : R^4 --> R^4 (linear transformation)

Characteristic polynomial --> p(x) = x^4-x^3, and also data that dim(ImT)=2.
The question is if T diagonalizable?

That what I did :

Since dim(ImT)=2, and T:R^4 --> R^4 we know that dim(KerT) = 2.
As well :

x^4-x^3 --> x^3(x-1)

So 0,1 are eigenvalue.

Since 0,1 are eigenvalue we can conclude that matrix is similar same characteristic polynomial.

So it possible to conclude that:

In case 1 eigenvalue, algebra multiplexing = 3, geometric multiplexing = (4-3) = 1

In case 0 eigenvalue, algebra multiplexing = 1, geometric multiplexing = (4-1) = 3

so T is not diagonalizable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general idea is correct but you made a couple mistakes. $0$ has an algebraic multiplicity of $3$ (and $1$ has an algebraic multiplicity of $1$, though this doesn't matter in this problem.) On the other hand, $0$ has geometric multiplicity of $2$: the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ is $\text{Ker } T$, which you correctly determined has dimension $2$. Since $2<3$, $T$ is not diagonalizable.

By the way, in general, the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue is less than or equal to its algebraic multiplicity. So it is not possible for an eigenvalue to have algebraic multiplicity $1$ and geometric multiplicity $3$.

Comment: Thank you, I was taught a way to calucate the geometric multiplicity, I wonder if it possible to use it in this question if not is there a way to calulate 1 geometric multiplicity.

0 has algebaric multiplicity of 3.
1 has algebaric multiplicity of 1.

I know that main diagonal is R^4 = (1,0,0,0) since the matrix (let's name the matrix A) is similar same characteristic polynomial which is x^3(x-1).

1I(identity matrix) - A = main diagonal R^4 (0,1,1,1) then P(A) = 3.
Then so the geometric multiplicity is n-P(A) (4-3) = 1
Same process for 0 in that case P(A) = 1, then n-P(A) (4-1) = 3

Comment: I don't know if this method could work in this case (incorrect answers) since I don't know the rest of the matrix, I only know the main digonal, I wonder if there's something wrong with my algorithm using that method or that method cannot be used in this question, Thank you.

Comment: $A$ in your problem is *not* similar to diag(1,0,0,0). Similarity transformations preserve both algebraic and geometric multiplicities of eigenvalues. Two similar matrices will have the same characteristic polynomial, but the converse is not true. That is, two matrices with the same characteristic polynomial need not be similar. For example $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ have the same characteristic polynomial $p(x)=(x-1)^2$ but they are not similar.

Comment: In case the rest of the matrix is zero (or triangle matrix), and the diag equals to (1,0,0,0) then it possible to calucate characteristic polymon using the main diagonal the characteristic polynomial is t^3(t-1), since the characteristic matrix is equals to diag(t-1, t, t, t) then the det(t-1,t,t,t) is equals to t^3(t-1) which is x^3(x-1).

Comment: Sure: and then depending on the entries below/above the diagonal, the geometric multiplicity of $0$ might be $1$, it might be $2$, or it might be $3$. Yet all such matrices have the same characteristic polynomial. Thus the characteristic polynomial gives essentially no information about geometric multiplicities.

Comment: Oh, actually haven't thought of that case, I made a wrong assumption, your right.

Comment: Of course the question could be solve without calucate eigenvalue 1 (since from eigenvalue 0 we know that T isn't diagonalizable) however I wonder if its possible to calucate eigenvalue 1?

Comment: $1$ will have geometric multiplicity $1$ in this situation. This is true of any situation where an eigenvalue has algebraic multiplicity $1$. But if this were $\mathbb{R}^5$ and you found that $0$ had algebraic multiplicity $3$ and $1$ had algebraic multiplicity $2$, you couldn't compute the geometric multiplicity of either one.

Comment: This is true since algebra multiplicity(which equals 1 in that case)>=geometric multiplicity>0?

Comment: That is correct.